# Why is this HTML/JavaScript question off topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

I was going through first posts and came across this question about why a collection in JavaScript was being logged as both empty and non empty at the same time when using different ways of logging it.

I didn't see anything wrong with this question (it could definitely been worded more clearly, but I think that can be expected when someone is asking a question about something they don't fully understand). So I decided it was ok. When looking back at the question today, I see it was marked as "Off-Topic". Is that right? Why?

*[How to covert HTML collection to an array, that gets updated as per DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59847428/how-to-covert-html-collection-to-an-array-that-gets-updated-as-per-dom)*

Comment: If that was the reason, shouldn't it be flagged as "Needs details or clarity"?

Comment: well... the question has quite a few... misconceptions. Each of which on their own have a duplicate, but nothing would cover so many separate issues unless we ignored all of the misconceptions and just dupe closed it for the actual problem: how to convert an html collection to an array. but even that can't really be done, because the user is asking for more than that, they're asking that the array remain dynamically updated like the collection is. The question is a mess.

Comment: and i'm not even sure if the dynamically updated part is even relevant, as they haven't shown what they need this for. Does it need to be an array?

Comment: Interesting, I guess I just thought they didn't understand why their array was empty. Not that they were asking how they can make an array from a collection and tie them together such that adding an element to one would update the other. It reads like "why is my list logged as both empty and not empty?" to me.

Comment: Also perhaps flagging it as "Needs more focus" would be more clear? I guess I just felt like "off-topic" doesn't make sense, especially with no explanation given.

Comment: I think off topic - needs more info is more appropriate, the current reason. *"Edit the question to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem. This will help others answer the question."* If that request is followed, we'd know what the user is doing and how to better help them.

Comment: I'm guessing that you aren't able to view that, and all you see is "off topic". i think off topic is a rather odd title to place that close reason under given that sub-reason is hidden from most users.

Comment: Got it! thanks! Yes that is it. I didn't realize there is a hidden reason that presumably the OP can see. If you post that answer I will accept it.

Comment: It's an interesting, not-entirely-intuitive issue. I don't think it's too broad at all. There's enough information to describe why OP is running into the issue he is, but not quite enough to say what the fix would be (which is probably the reason for off-topic closure, which is understandable) (though it'll very likely end up being a near dupe of [the canonical](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959))